# Distinct function broken in MySQL 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by, distinct

I have the following code that has stopped working since MySQL 5.7 upgrade:

```
$myDB->contentArray = $myDB->executeAssoc("
       SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(displayDate)) as year FROM
       `inlineItemData_standardList` 
       WHERE `inlineItemGroupID` = $inlineItemGroupID 
       ORDER BY `displayDate` desc");
```

Could anyone show me how I would replace the DISTINCT part in this? I have searched around and can find others with the same issue but without a lot of PHP knowledge, I can't seem to implement the correct thing. I tried using GROUP BY 'YEAR(displayDate)) as year' but can't seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it has but not because of DISTINCT, More detail please with sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: "stopped working" . What error did it cause? Did it simply return no results or was it actually a fault report?

Comment: DISTINCT is NOT a function. ```SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(displayDate) as `year` FROM ..```

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. The error it’s throwing is:  Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'my_dbnew.inlineItemData_standardList.displayDate' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` clause of a `SELECT DISTINCT` query must be consistent with the `SELECT` clause.

So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(displayDate) as year 
FROM inlineItemData_standardList
WHERE inlineItemGroupID = ?
ORDER BY YEAR(displayDate) DESC
-- Or: ORDER BY `year` DESC
```

Side note: use prepared statements! Do not concatenate variables in the query string: this is both inefficient and unsafe. Recommended reading: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/10676716)